# How to embed a webpack bundled react app to another site

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, webpack

I have a react app that I bundled up using webpack. The code I bundled is a chatbot and I hosted it using Netlify. I am trying to embed a script that points to that bundled code. However, when I add the script to the bottom before the body tag none of the react components are rendering. I added a console log in the bundled code and that shows up in the console. but the elements are not showing up in the DOM.

This a create-react-app site I added the script to to test it. **No Errors show up in the console** and the chatbot-bundle is a file built by webpack and it only contains the code used to create the chatbot.

What I want to happen is after embedding this script to the html file, the chatbot widget would render in the bottom right corner of the page.

[image]

[image]

The file is loaded in the sources to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you actually inject or use in a different website will have to inject a div element with id e.g. `my-id` to the html tree and then call react.render itself. Or if the cra you are showing is where the chatbot should be hosted, then the chatbot script should render to this div#id, so you would have to add it to index.html or inject through script.

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <Chatbot />,
  document.getElementById('my-id')
);
```